# How to show date with previous post link in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

When viewing a post, I want to show the date of the previous post underneath the previous/next post links but $post is not available in previous_post_link().

How can I carry forward the post date from the previous post as well as get the date for the next link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did a bit of searching on the web, but no result. Then I opened the file wp-include/link-tempalte.php.

On line 1327 you will find `next_post_link` which calls `adjacent_post_link` function.
This function again calls `get_adjacent_post` function to retrieve previous post data.

Looking at the source, you should be able to do the following:

```
  $in_same_cat = false; 
  $excluded_categories = '';
  $previous = true;
  $post = get_adjacent_post($in_same_cat, $excluded_categories, $previous);
  echo $post->post_date;
```

This is not tested, but I think it hould work.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Alas, the post array returned by get_adjacent_post() doesn't have post_date but it does have the post ID (albeit in form http://example.com?p=21) so I can probably fudge it from here.

Comment: Back up! There is a post ID and date! It was being munged by the CSS.