# Display post date on previous/next link

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am about modifying the previous post (and next post) link in Wordpress. but I don't know how to show **the date** of the referred post.

I don't want an external plugin for this answer, but the code in functions.php will be great.
(Note: [I have read this. if this is the answer how to use it in very practical code?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3675396/how-to-show-date-with-previous-post-link-in-wordpress)

the final result should be like this:

< Previous (12 June 2011) | Current Post | (14 June 2011) Next >

Answer (score 1):

The following code will output the link in the correct format from your single.php template:

```
    <?php $prev_post = get_previous_post(); ?>
    <a href="<?php echo get_page_link($prev_post->ID); ?>">&lt; (<?php echo mysql2date('d F Y', $prev_post->post_date, false) ?>) Previous</a>
```

I'll leave the next link as an exercise for you.

Comment: yes, it redirects the current post to prev/next. but the 'categories' also counted in the link. how to exclude it

Comment: This sounds like a separate question Edy?

Comment: I've tested this on some posts of mine and it works as expected, it links to the previously published post.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo get_the_date( 'd/m/Y' ); ?>
```

this will also show the date even posts within a day